# How to a new element to JFrame and have it show

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe, auto-update

I have a GUI with a scroll pane in it. The Scroll Pane is scrolling though a JPanel of JPanels. I would like the ability to add one more to the list of subJPanels and have the JFrame update to do it.

Right now I have the array updating, but not the JFrame.

---

```
package SSCCE;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Add extends JFrame{
    private JPanel[] branches;
    private JPanel pane; //Pane that stores accounts
    private JScrollPane scroller;
    private JButton newBranch;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new Add();
    }

    public Add(){
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(500, 500);
        this.setTitle("How Do I add?");

        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        this.add(statusBar(), BorderLayout.NORTH);

        populateBranches();

        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(branches.length,1));
        for (int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
            pane.add(branches[i]);
        }

        scroller = new JScrollPane(pane);
        scroller.createVerticalScrollBar();
        this.add(scroller,BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JPanel statusBar(){
        JPanel statusBar = new JPanel();
        statusBar.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        newBranch = new JButton("New Branch");
                newBranch.addActionListener(new ButtonEventHandler());

        statusBar.add(newBranch);
        return statusBar;
    }

    private void populateBranches(){
        branches = new JPanel[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
            branches[i] = new JPanel();
            branches[i].setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            branches[i].add(new JTextField(20));
        }
    }

    private void newBranch(){
        JPanel[] tempBranches = new JPanel[branches.length + 1];
                System.out.println(tempBranches.length);

        for (int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
            tempBranches[i] = branches[i];
        }

        tempBranches[branches.length] = new JPanel();
        tempBranches[branches.length].setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        tempBranches[branches.length].add(new JTextField(20));
        branches = tempBranches;

        pane = new JPanel();
        pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(branches.length, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < branches.length; i++){
            pane.add(branches[i]);
        }
                pane.repaint();
                pane.validate();

        scroller = new JScrollPane(pane);
        this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.repaint();
        this.validate();
    }

    private class ButtonEventHandler implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            String btnClkd = event.getActionCommand();
            if (btnClkd.equals("New Branch")){
                newBranch();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `JButton newBranch` haven't access to `ButtonEventHandler` by add `ActionListener` to `JButton newBranch` or am I wrong remove `this.` and `extends JFrame{`,  create `JFrame` as local variable (like as `JButton newBranch`)

Comment: this.add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER); &        this.repaint(); & 
        this.validate(); could be myFrame.Xxx

Comment: this.setLayout(new BorderLayout()); JFrame has  BorderLayout in API, then this code is useless, but  BorderLayout isn't proper LayoutManager for add component at runtime, because only one JCOmponent can be placed to one of 5th areas

Comment: @mKorbel yeah, I noticed that. I updated the code to include that, that was not the issue.

Comment: @mKorbel what do you recommend if not BorderLayout?

Comment: you can to use GridLayout for JFrame too, you can to start with, because looks like as all elements has the same size

Comment: @mKorBel I have a GridLayout because there are more things that go on the screen. I simplified the code, so there is only the one button at the top, but in the real program there are a lot more. 

The center pane IS a GridLayout.

Comment: I'll post my idea as an answer

Comment: @mKorbel I added pane.repaint() and .validate() and it make a difference, I doens't work 100% but it's better. I adjusted in the code, maybe you can take a look at that before you post an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you allow the GridLayout to grow, You can simply add more components to it:

```
// 0 means new rows are added as needed
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

// ...

private void newBranch(){
    // Create the component
    JPanel branch = new JPanel();
    branch.add(new JTextField(20));
    // + any additional subcomponents

    // and just add it where the others already are
    pane.add(branch);
    pane.revalidate();
}
```